# SparkSQL-Scala Program : First-column should contains lowest string among (col1,col2) of each row

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Need Output where first-column should contains lowest string among (column1,column2) of each row.

I am getting error : Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

I am trying to use UDF to return minimum and maximum value of a two string, and use it in sql statement.

> "select minUDF(name1,name2), maxUDF(name1,name2) from friends"

Don't know where i am doing wrong.
Can somebody please help me to find my mistake?

````
Input :           Required Output :
+-----+-----+     +-----+-----+
|name1|name2|     |name1|name2|
+-----+-----+     +-----+-----+
| shir| amit|     | amit| shir|
| bane| shir|     | bane| shir|
| shir| raj |     |  raj| shir|
| amit| shir|     | amit| shir|
| xiag| alan|     | alan| xiag|
| shir|  raj|     |  raj| shir|
+-----+-----+     +-----+-----+

import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}

object test {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {


    val spark=SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local[*]").getOrCreate();
    val sc=spark.sparkContext

    case class friends(name1:String,name2:String)
    val rdd=sc.parallelize(Seq(Row("shir","amit"),Row("amit","shir"),Row("raj","shir"),Row("amit","shir"),Row("raj","shir"),Row("shir","raj")))

    val schema=StructType(Array(
      StructField("name1",StringType,true),
      StructField("name2",StringType,true)
    ))

    val df=spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
    df.show()

    val minfun = (str1:String,str2:String)=>{

      if(str1.compareTo(str2)<0)
        return str1
      else
        return str2

    }

    val maxfun = (str1:String,str2:String)=>{

      if(str1.compareTo(str2)>0)
        return str1
      else
        return str2

    }

    spark.udf.register("minUDF",minfun)
    spark.udf.register("maxUDF",maxfun)

    df.createOrReplaceTempView("friends")
    val ddd = spark.sql("select minUDF(name1,name2), maxUDF(name1,name2) from friends")
    ddd.show

    spark.stop()

  }
}```
````

Comment: As far as I can see from [here](https://users.scala-lang.org/t/return-expressions-in-functions/2603) (`return` relates to the innermost enclosing method), your functions should be declared in a way similar to this: `val minfun = (str1: String, str2: String) => if (str1.compareTo(str2) < 0) str1 else str2` (same for the other function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do not write UDF when we have built-in functions for the same:

Try to use SQL least and greatest function to calculate min and max:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.least

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.greatest

val ddd = spark.sql("select least(name1,name2), greatest(name1,name2) from friends")

ddd.show
```

Also try to avoid using UDF because they need to serialize among all the worker nodes which will incurred you the cost of Serialization and Deserialization.